# Apps on an SD Card Using Symbolic Linking

Tags: ipad, jailbreak, sd-card

I would like to be able to store Apps on a SD card, and play with symbolic linking. I was able to make this work, however my SD card can't be unmounted, is there any good way to do this, without copying the apps?

Comment: what is the symbolic link command you're using?

Comment: SpringBoard is most likely using the files on that disk, so it'll always be busy. Did your apps actually open when you tried this? This is actually a great question you have here.

Comment: I wonder if I could get the Camera Connection Kit to work on the iPhone and test this out myself. **Edit:** There's a tweak called CameraConnector that sets it all up for use with iPhone.